# Proguard Syntax: How filters like "{ *; }", "{ }" and "<empty>" work?

Tags: android, proguard

I have an Android application that was fixed with the following rule:

```
-keep com.my.package.MyClass { *; }
```

According to [Proguard's documentation](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage#classspecification), this
brace filter means that *"any field or method"* from `MyClass` would be kept intact.

The thing is, before applying `{ *; }` to my rule, I always thought that

```
-keep com.my.package.MyClass
```

which was the rule before fixing it, or

```
-keep com.my.package.MyClass { }
```

had the same meaning, since brace parameters are considered optional. In other words from my interpretation so far, if I'm not specifying a filter, anything should be matched.

[image]

Since official documentation is not pretty clear and Proguard has also no official support, does anybody know the difference between those three rules or could even better exemplify how they work internally?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As [Proguard's documentation](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/home) suggests, working with it is slightly empirical.

> *"For proper results, you should at least be somewhat familiar with the
> code that you are processing. Obfuscating code that performs a lot of
> reflection may require *TRIAL AND ERROR*, especially without the
> necessary information about the internals of the code."*

Further work made me realize that not specifying a filter has the same impact as specifying an empty one.

```
-keep com.my.package.MyClass
-keep com.my.package.MyClass { }
```

When shrinking or obfuscating members, to not mention filters at all means that none should be kept intact.

```
-keepclassmembernames com.my.package.MyClass
-keepclassmembernames com.my.package.MyClass { }
```

On the other hand,

```
-keepclassmembernames com.my.package.MyClass { *; }
```

`{ *; }` matches anything inside the class, which is the same as saying

> *"Obfuscate and shrink MyClass but leave everything inside it untouched".*

Obfuscation and shrinking might be applied to the class itself, but the shrink phase defined by `-keepclassmembernames`  won't affect constructors (represented by `<init>();` according to Proguard's syntax) or other members (`<fields>();` & `<methods>();`).